# Recursive formula for tiling a n unit walkway with the condition of no RR, or GGG pattern in the sequence.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recursive-algorithms

Let's say you have three different kinds of tiles. All one unit in length. We'll call them Red(R), Green(G), and Blue(B). Create a recursive formula to tile an n unit long walkway where the only condition is that you can't have two reds or three green tiles next to each other.

I tried this problem by thinking about it from the end of the sequence.

Define $R_n$ be the number of ways that you can have a length $n$ walkway with red at the end.

Define $G_n$ be the number of ways that you can have a length $n$ walkway with green at the end.

Define $B_n$ be the number of ways that you can have a length $n$ walkway with blue at the end.

Define $W_n$ be the number of ways that you can have a length $n$ walkway.

$$R_n = B_{n-1} + G_{n-1}$$

$$G_n = B_{n-1} + R_{n-1} + B_{n-2}+R_{n-2}$$

$$B_n = W{n-1}$$

However, when you put this together, you have an extra $R_{n-2}$ that I can't figure out how to put in terms of $W$. Where am I going wrong?

$W_n = 2W_{n-1} + W_{n-2} + W_{n-3} + R_{n-2}$

Comment: Hi Lucas. Problems like this are of the "hands-on" type, meaning they involve playing around in the sense of trial-and-error and sketching some walkways, to see what happens. Have you tried that? You might tell us about it. (Note the 'Edit' button above.)

Comment: You should define your terms.  Presumably $R_n$ is the number of ways to tile an $n$ unit walkway ending in red and so on.  Your formula for $R_n$ is correct.  What is $W_n$? (I have a guess)  The $G_n$ formula is wrong.  If $n=3$ the walkway $BBG$ is counted twice, once in $B_1$ and once in $B_2$

Comment: Yeah my mistake, W is the walkway. Perhaps I should've included let statements. However, Bn-2 and Rn-2 is I believe equal to Gn-1. What do you mean by B1 and B2?

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't think he overcounted. In the Green formula, $B_{n-2}$ and $R_{n-2}$ only means that the last tile is green (second to last isn't). Using your example of $n=3$, $B_1$ is the case of $BGG$ and $B_2$ has the case of $BBG$.

Comment: By $B-1$ I meant the number of ways to tile a $1$ square walkway ending in blue, so it is $1$ to count $B$.  $B_2=3$ to count $RB, GB, BB$.  I see your $n-2$s in the equation for $G_n$ envision adding two greens to an $n-2$ walkway, so that is right.  You may not be able to substitute to get a formula for $W_n$ without any other colors.  Another way to make a column vector $[B_n\ R_n\ G_n\ B_{n-1}\ R_{n-1}\ G_{n-1}]^T$ and write the equation as updating that vector by multiplying by a $6 \times 6$ matrix.  Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.